# Scroll view not working properly using relative layout

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-relativelayout

For a tablet, using relative layout I used scroll view but it doesn't works out. What I am missing here?

**Source:**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
         android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
         android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
         android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
         tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <ImageView
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:id="@+id/imageView1"
             android:src="@drawable/logo"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
         // More Buttons, images and text views here.... 
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Based on your snippet here I can tell you so far that the ScrollView is supposed to have only 1 direct child element.

Comment: I think the same, but it's the formatting that appears to have more than one

Comment: What doesn't work? You have sufficient data to generate a scroll?

Comment: Scrolling is not happening, even if I try the `FrameLayout` inside it. Also when I add a `<VideoView>` after the `<ImageView>`, the video Player is not displaying. If I remove the scroll view I can see the video player. why this is happening ?

Comment: try to add a layout and inside it add your scrollView

Comment: because i everytime use scrollView inside RelativeLayout and everything is ok

Comment: Try adding android:fillViewPort="true" to scroll view

Comment: I just copied your ScrollView and your RelativeLayout and added it to my layout which had other controls. Everything worked just fine and scrolling worked. From the code snippet your posted there is nothing wrong in it and it is supposed to work. So my guess is that either it is the rest of the layout or the code that is causing some problem.

Answer (score 0):

try making your RelativeLayout height "wrap_content" instead of match parent.

Answer (score 0):

Both the layout_height attributes of your RelativeLayout and ScrollView must be wrap_content and not match_parent.

**Updated code:**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <ImageView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:id="@+id/imageView1"
           android:src="@drawable/logo"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <!-- More Buttons, images and text views here....  -->
</RelativeLayout>
```